# How to catch exceptions in a python run_in_executor method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, asynchronous, python-asyncio

How can i raise the exception in the run_long_thing() function called with the run_in_executor?
It looks like it is being swallowed. I don't need the result of the function in the blocking code. It is basically a fire and forget function, but still i need to catch the exceptions if there are any...

```
import asyncio
import time


def fire_and_forget(task, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if callable(task):
        #if threadpoolworker is set to None,
        #the max_workers will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, task, *args, **kwargs)
    else:    
        raise TypeError('Task must be a callable.')


async def run_long_thing(sleep):
    print("Doing long thing... {:}".format(sleep))
    time.sleep(sleep)
    print("Done doing long thing. {:}".format(sleep))
    raise Exception("sh*t happens")


def do_it():
    print("Starting my main thing...")
    print("Calling my long thing...")
    for i in range(0,10,1):
        try:
            fire_and_forget(run_long_thing, i)
            print(i)
            print("Pom pi dom...")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("POOOOM Pom pi dom...")
        except:
            print("can i see the sh*t?")

do_it()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first of all, if you call `time.sleep` you'll never end up running the `asyncio` event loop so no results will get detected.  instead of calling `time.sleep` in `do_it` you're better off doing something like

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.1))
```

Now,  the return from run_in_executor is a future.  If you don't mind writing an async def and using `create_task` on your `asyncio` loop you could do something like

```
async def run_long_thing(thing, *args):
    try: await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, thing, *args)
    except:
        #do stuff
```

But more in line with your current code you can attach an exception callback

```
def callback(future):
if future.exception(): #your long thing had an exception
        # do something with future.exception()
```

then when you call run_in_executor:

```
future = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, fun, *args)
future.add_done_callback(callback)
```

Then `callback` will be called whenever your executor task completes.  `future.result()` will contain the result if it is no an exception, and `future.exception()` will give you back any raised exception